# Two clients on a single thread Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

I am writing a program in which I have a server that is continuously listening for requests (like most servers). I want it to create a new thread each time I get a client connection(I'm done with this part), and I want it to add the client immediately after it, to the same thread. So I'll have two clients connected to the same thread.

Something along the lines of:

```
.....
try(ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket();
    Socket client1 = serversocket.accept();
    Socket client2 = serversocket.accept();){

    //spawn new thread with sockets to client1 and client2
```

Is this possible? Are there any alternatives to this? Would it be possible to get two different threads to converse with each other?

Would it be possible to create a new server socket from the thread extending to a client?

```
...
try(ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket();
    Socket client1 = serversocket.accept();){
    //spawn thread
}
```

And now in the thread:

```
....
try(ServerSocket serversocket2 = new ServerSocket();
    Socket client2 = serversocket2.accept();){
    //exchange information between two clients and do other stuff
}
```

Any ideas? All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question that comes to mind is, why?

Comment: I'm trying to make a virtual version of many different two player board games. If you have any other ways I can do this, feel free to drop an answer.

Comment: Connection one, establishes some kind of group/identifier, connection two asks to join the same "group" if it exists.  Both connections reside within their own threads...?

Comment: But how do I create the group?! I came with pretty much the same thing, but I don't know how to get two threads to communicate between each other.

Comment: That's up to you. You could use a `Map`, or some other kind of lookup mechanism, where the group is managing the information passing between the two connections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you make an `ArrayList` and you could make a `ClientThread` class or something and it's constructor takes a `Socket` argument. Then when you get a new connection, do something like

```
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
arrayList.add(new ClientThread(clientSocket));
```

Comment: That's not what I want. I have that in my server class and I spawn a new thread each time I receive a connection. And in that thread that was newly created I want to create a new socket and add just one client to that socket. What you're trying to do seems to be adding infinite clients to the same socket and having them wait for their turn. That's not what I want to do.

Comment: So are you trying to get two client threads to communicate with each other?

Comment: Yes, yes. That's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So you need help with the actual creating Threads part, not the communicating part, right?

Comment: But I still don't know which clients are supposed to talk to each other.

Comment: Wouldn't you determine that in your code? Wait so lets say you have client 1, 2, and 3. So you don't know whether client 1 is supposed to talk with 2, or 2 is supposed to talk with 3, etc.?

Comment: Oh, ok! So, using the index of the array list of the specific threads right? That makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, you would select the thread at arrayList position 0, for example, by using `arrayList.get(0);`
Here's the Java API page for [ArrayList:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Ok, I'll try this, it should work. I'll come back and mark this as the answer that worked.

Comment: When I try to add threads to an arraylist it gives me this error message:" 'void' type not allowed here".

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why we use different threads for different clients is so that the clients can be handled individually, without blocking up other clients who may be wanting different things. If you wanted to extend your program afterwards, say, to have different difficulty levels for clients, you would need a different setup.

When a client connects, a new thread is started and a flag is set in a flag table on the server, saying "Client available" (maybe with more info about the client; eg. difficulty level). Then the server tells the client that a suitable opponent is being waited for, and goes back into waiting. When a suitable opponent does connect, the corresponding flag contains *references* to both clients and now you have two threads with suitable clients.

Assuming the games are turn-based and not real-time, the game can be played as follows: at the start, each client requests the server for the socket corresponding to the other client, which the server gives it, looking up the reference in the flag table above. Then, the clients decide on the game, options, etc. between themselves by communicating over the socket. Once both the clients know what the empty board looks like, they start playing; they send each other *changes* on the board, like 'knight to d5'. They handle finishing on their own, or maybe keeping a record on the server.

In the code, you need to use *synchronized methods* and *thread-safe objects* whenever dealing with separate threads trying to communicate. You could read further about it at [the Java Tutorials page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: But with this scenario, I'll only be able to have one game going on on each server. What if I want as many games as possible? Then how do I know which thread1(first client that connected) talks to which thread2(second client that connected)?

Comment: @Fazer Edited accordingly.

Comment: What exactly wold you define as a reference? How would they differ between client pairs?

Comment: Like @I1zZY says, you could simply add the threads to an ArrayList which holds Threads. Or you could give them names, and refer to them by name.

Comment: When I try to add threads to an arraylist it gives me this error message:" 'void' type not allowed here".

Comment: At what exact line does it give the error like what is the code line you typed?